# Content security policy blocking CKEditor write function in from bundled script in Django website application

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, content-security-policy, ckeditor5

In my Django website application, I am using CKEditor 5.1.1 and a bundled script is being blocked by my `script-src` directive in my content security policy.

The offending file is `bundle-5f73f48756.cms.ckeditor.min.js`.
Specifically, the `write(a)` function from the block of code below is being flagged in the console:

```
write: function(a) {
                    this.$.open("text/html", "replace");
                    CKEDITOR.env.ie && (a = a.replace(/(?:^\s*<!DOCTYPE[^>]*?>)|^/i, '$\x26\n\x3cscript data-cke-temp\x3d"1"\x3e(' + CKEDITOR.tools.fixDomain + ")();\x3c/script\x3e"));
                    this.$.write(a);
                    this.$.close()
                },
```

I have tried writing middleware (with the help of ChatGPT) to address the issue.
I have successfully done this with other popup or inline scripts but in this case, the middleware does not work.

The goal there was to inject my nonce into the script tag from the `replace()` function but nonetheless, the error persists.

ChatGPT also suggested editing the configuration for CKEditor. However, since it is a "site-package" I am not sure where in my Django project I can actually update or override the configuration.

For context, the path to my base.py (settings) file is `marketing/marketing/settings/base.py`